# I have a code. It works fine till I put an extra method in it

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have my code with two classes. If I start the code, I get an Image. The Image has that long a white bar on the down till I have the two last methods getHeight and getWidth.

Now my question: Why everything works fine without these two methods? I was told that I should have these two API methods to to test later with JUnit.

Sry, for my bad english ;)

```
package mydraw;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class DrawImageMini {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ColorException {new DrawImageMini();}

/** Application constructor:  create an instance of our GUI class */
public DrawImageMini() throws ColorException { window = new DrawMiniGUI(this); }

protected JFrame window;
}

class DrawMiniGUI extends JFrame {
DrawImageMini app;
Container       cp;
NavigationPanel navigationPanel;
JPanel          drawPanel;

/**
 * The GUI constructor does all the work of creating the GUI and setting
 * up event listeners.  Note the use of local and anonymous classes.
 */
public DrawMiniGUI(DrawImageMini application) throws ColorException {
    super("Draw");        // Create the window
    app = application;    // Remember the application reference

    // selector for drawing modes
    JComboBox shape_chooser = new JComboBox();
    shape_chooser.addItem("Scribble");
    shape_chooser.addItem("Rectangle");
    shape_chooser.addItem("Oval");

    // selector for drawing colors
    JComboBox color_chooser = new JComboBox();
    color_chooser.addItem("Black");
    color_chooser.addItem("Blue");
    color_chooser.addItem("Red");
    color_chooser.addItem("Green");

    // Create two buttons
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");

    // Set a LayoutManager, and add the choosers and buttons to the window.
    cp = this.getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Setzt einen Panel, die Buttons in einer Leiste hat.
    navigationPanel = new NavigationPanel(new FlowLayout());
    navigationPanel.add(new JLabel("Shape:"));
    navigationPanel.add(shape_chooser);
    navigationPanel.add(new JLabel("Color:"));
    navigationPanel.add(color_chooser);
    navigationPanel.add(quit);
    navigationPanel.add(clear);
    navigationPanel.setBackground(Color.magenta);

    // Setzt den Panel, auf dem gemalt wird
    drawPanel = new JPanel();

    cp.add(navigationPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH, 0);
    cp.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER, 1);

    // Handle the window close request similarly
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            app.window.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    // Finally, set the size of the window, and pop it up
    drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    this.pack();
    drawPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public int getHeight(){
    return drawPanel.getHeight();
}

public int getWidth(){
    return drawPanel.getWidth();
}
}
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? How do you know it doesn't work? Please update your question to include that information even though ControlAltDel's answer is probably the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getWidth` and `getHeight` are already defined in `Component`, a super class of JFrame. You should not override these methods. Rather, you should name your methods something different

Comment: Or even better: don't extend `JFrame` :D. But your answer is still correct :).